# How disable Offline Error Alert on Parse.com iOS?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, alert, offline

I would like to disable Parse's Offline Error UIalert that shows up when there's no internet connection. I already manage the "No Internet Connection" with a pretty uiview. It is really annoying to have the Parse's pop up showing up every 15 seconds, it's a bit too much...

How can I do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a class method available `+ (void)offlineMessagesEnabled:(BOOL)enabled;`

Call it using `[Parse offlineMessagesEnabled:NO];`